# Seaching substring in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I am learning the basics of Python programming. The program should print all the strings containing substring "ba" from a defined list. The program doesn't provide the expected output. I have analyzed the code and tried every possible change without success. Please check it and help me out with the solution.

Thanks in advance!!

```
"""list"""
ls = ["black", "back", "bag", "bleach", "biba", "adabas"]
el = len(ls)
ind1 = 0
sublen = len(ls[ind1])
ind2 = 0
cha1 = "b"
cha2 = "a"

"""printing vals to see if they r not giving any error"""
print(sublen)
print(ls[ind1])
print(ls[ind1][ind2])
print(ls[ind1][ind2 + 1])

"""while loop to get the strings having 'ba' in them"""
while ind1 < el:
    while ind2 < sublen:
        if cha1 == ls[ind1][ind2] and cha2 == ls[ind1][ind2 + 1]:
            print(ls[ind1])
        ind2 += 1
    ind1 += 1
print("finished!!")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ls = ["black", "back", "bag", "bleach", "biba", "adabas"]

for item in ls:
    if 'ba' in item:
        print(item)
```

The output is:

```
back
bag
biba
adabas
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the simplified and better solution !! :) However can you please let me know what is wrong with my program. I could not find any error in the code :|

Comment: I found the error just now. I was not resetting the counter var ind2 once the inner while loop is getting executed. 

ls = ["back", "black", "bag", "bleach", "biba", "adabas"]
el = len(ls)
ind1 = 0
sublen = len(ls[ind1])
ind2 = 0
cha1 = "b"
cha2 = "a"

while ind1 < el:
    while ind2 < sublen:
         if (ind2 + 1) < len(ls[ind1]):
             if cha1 == ls[ind1][ind2] and cha2 == ls[ind1][ind2 + 1]:
                 print(ls[ind1])
         ind2 += 1
    ind2=0
    ind1 += 1
print("finished!!")